# Scaling of a bone is working while rotation is not Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3d and I'm trying to rotate the left leg bone of an avatar but it is not working although scaling is working well.

This is the code used for scaling and is working perfect:

```
 r.localScale += new Vector3( 0.1f , 0.1f , 0.1f);
```

and these are my attempts to is the code of rotation but not working:

```
 r.eulerAngles = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);                            
 r.rotation = transform.rotation * r.rotation;
```

where r is the transform of the left leg.

EDIT:

I tried the answer below but still not working. This is my [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phd0taehdk6omi7/Test.cs?dl=0).

So this doesn't work when I'm using the `Update` function, like nothing happens to the avatar.
If I used `LateUpdate` function, I can see the rotation made but then flickers back to the old position, I wonder how to apply the rotation to all the remaining frames as well.

If anyone could please advise

Comment: If you use another values can you see changes in your object? 
Maybe you can try to follow this example and when you get some results   adapt your code.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Comment: @mayo tried it but not working, nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are always setting the r.rotation be the same value every time you do this, and then multiple the same value every time. so unless transform.rotation changes r.rotation will always be the same value.

try 
`r.rotation = r.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(10f, 10f, 10f);`
this will multiple the rotation of r by the same amount each time.

Comment: The reason you are seeing that "Update" doesnt work is because it appears that this bone is being animated, "LateUpdate" gets called after the animation is applied to the bones that have keys on them. In order to have this keep getting applied you will have to do it every frame, since the animation will override any changes you make to during the next frame (if it has keys for that bone).